# How would I go about counting the number of times an external app has been opened and for how long?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm a beginner to Android app development, and as a good personal project to get started I'm trying to re-create something akin to [StayFree](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.burockgames.timeclocker) or [Checky](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.calm.checky). I want my app to be able to both count how much time a user has spent in an app during a day and how many times the app has been opened during the day.

I was thinking I could store the data using SharedPreferences, and came across [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive#java) page in the Android developers documentation that I think could be useful in solving my problem, but, at a high level, I still don't really know what the outline would look like.

Comment: What do you mean by outline? If you are not sure about the implementation steps, then I would suggest for you to familiarize yourself further with Android development first (follow tutorials, read documentations, and try to implement stuffs)

Comment: I don't think so you can get the such data from other apps unless they are providing such data through a ContentProvider, which is highly unlikely.